# Batch-file string builder

Tags: string, batch-file, output, stringbuilder

I want to create a string builder to combine the line contents of a .txt-file by using a batch file so I can import it later on(CSV).

The source file contains lines of information that repeat themselves after for example 3 times. Like this:

```
Info1 a
Info2 b
Info3 c
Info1 aa
Info2 DD
Info3 ff
```

The new target file should look like this:

```
Info1 a; Info2 b; Info3 c
Info1 aa; Info2 dd; Info3 ff
```

This is my start code:

```
set OutFile=D:\outfile.txt 
if exist %OutFile% del /q %OutFile%
set counter=0;
for /F "tokens=*" %%y in (D:\list.txt) do (
if %counter% == 0 do (
set string=%%y
)
if %counter% == 2 do (
 echo %string%>>%OutFile%
)

if %counter% != 0  && %counter% != 2 do (
set string=%string% and ";" and %%y
)
)
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified a little bit your sourcefile:

- Instead of removing the output file if it exists, always create an empty one (the `copy` command)
- `_RepeatCount` holds the number of lines when the pattern repeats (change it if the input file format changes)
- I am using [delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html)
- The algorithm is simple: I iterate to each line of the input file, and add it to a variable that holds the already read lines; every time I read `_RepeatCount` lines, I dump the variable into the output file and reset it. the last `if` clause if is for handling cases where the input files doesn't have a number of lines that is multiple of `_RepeatCount`, they will be dumped in the output file as well.

Here's the code:

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions, enabledelayedexpansion

set OutFile=D:\outfile.txt 
copy NUL %OutFile%

set InFile=D:\list.txt

set _RepeatCount=3
set _Index=0

for /F "tokens=*" %%y in (%InFile%) do (
    set /A _Index=_Index + 1
    if !_Index! equ %_RepeatCount% (
        set _Lines=!_Lines!%%y
        set _Index=0
        echo !_Lines! >> %OutFile%
        set _Lines=
    ) else (
        set _Lines=!_Lines!%%y; 
    )
)
if "%_Lines%" neq "" (
    echo %_Lines% >> %OutFile%
)
```